# i18n jira problems

Tags: java, internationalization, jira

im not sure if its a jira problem or me not doing it properly, the latter more likely!

I have a file properties file called rootcause it is in a directory sturcture net/mycompany/rootcauseanalysis

in my jira atlassian-plugin.xml file I have

`<resource type="i18n" name="i18n" location="net.mycompany.rootcauseanalysis.rootcause"/>`

in my properties file I have properties defined like

`rootcause.name=My plugin`

in my java file which extends `JiraWebActionSupport` i use

`String str=getText("rootcause.name");`

when I print this out I get rootcause.name instead of the My plugin value I was expecting to get.

I have tried troubleshooting this problem by changing directory structure, file names, property names, using " and ' running out of ideas now!

Comment: Couldnt find anything on jira that was much help but this confluence guide was helpful gettting to where i am now
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DISC/i18n+in+Confluence+Plugin+Development

Comment: Just another troubleshooting idea: I'd run a file monitor and grepped for "rootcause" to see what file does JIRA try to open. It's "procmon" on Windows or "strace" on Linux.

Comment: Thanks i will follow that up. I have done a bit more, if i change the location in the xml file i get resource bundle errors and it wont load the plugin so its obviously finding the properties file.

when i try and read the file am i meant to be specifying anywhere else which file it should read?

Comment: made some progress. This works in my velocity template `$i18n.getText('test.name')` still no luck in the java file though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

done it :D

This is a hack I found on the forums solved my problem

http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?messageID=257351842&#257351842